# Determining the splitting ratio when augmenting image data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, sampling, data-augmentation, train-test-split

I have an image dataset that is quite imbalanced, with one class having 2873 images and another having only 115. The rest of the classes have ~250 images each. For reducing the imbalance, I decided to split the dataset into Train-Valid-Test components, with the major class having less proportion of images in the training set compared to the minor classes.
Then I'll be augmenting the data in the training set. I intend to perform an 80-10-10 split on the dataset.

**Which outcome shall be considered as an 80-10-10 split?**

- **Splitting the dataset in the proportion 80-10-10, and THEN augmenting the training images (which would eventually result in >80% proportion for the training set after augmentation).**
- **Splitting the dataset in a proportion such that it eventually results in an 80-10-10 split AFTER augmentation.**

**Also, is it acceptable to have an 85-7.5-7.5 split, provided it reduces imbalance in the dataset?**

Answer (score 0):

First, the splitting of the dataset should be stratified which means that each class should exist in the training, test and validation sets with the defined proportions.

The data augmentation should only be applied on the training dataset, no need to apply it on the test data because its main goal is to improve the performance and outcomes of the models by making different examples in the train dataset. So, there is no need to apply data augmentation on the test and validation sets.

For the last question, it is possible whatever proportions you want for test and validation as long as they give you enough data to evaluate the model